# Try to install Numpy: SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'

Tags: linux, python-2.7, numpy, yocto

I am currently using Cisco that runs on a yocto distr version of Linux. It has already installed Python 2.7.3, and we want to install numpy for this python. 
However, when I try to do `python setup.py install`, it gives me:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Appearently, it is a problem because of the fact that I didn't install python-devel.
Because the Cisco machine hasn't configured to internet connection (it is difficult to configure), and I am unable to just do `sudo apt-get install python-dev` to just crab the file for me.

What can I do to solve this error (without internet connection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the python-dev deb file to an external drive from somewhere with an internet connection, mount the drive on the Cisco and install the .deb with

```
# dpkg -i debfile.deb
```

Edit: If you also need to install dependencies, try this: http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/517